# How to change UIBarButtonItem text during runtime "cleanly" (Edit --> Done --> Edit)?

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I'm trying to change UIBarButtonItem text "cleanly" during runtime so that Edit/Done modes can be toggled. Every time I change the title attribute during runtime, however, the animation seems clumsy. I'm looking to emulate the appearance and function of the Edit/Done button in the Contacts app (where Edit simply fades and Done appears in its place).

```
@IBAction func editDoneButtonPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

    if(sender.title == "Edit"){
        sender.title = "Done"
    }else{
        sender.title = "Edit"
    }

}
```

Initial settings: Identifier is set to "custom" and Title is set to "Edit"

Simpler programatical solutions are preferred, however, the appearance of the animation is indeed paramount. I'd consider toggling the UIBarButtonItem identifier, rather than its text attribute, however, I'm not sure of an elegant way to toggle the identifier during runtime.

BTW: I'm using Swift to construct the app.

Links to...

Screencast of Contacts app Edit/Done toggle animation:
https://youtu.be/5mT_vzpNhIw

Screencast of my Edit/Done toggle animation:
https://youtu.be/mEweotJNVNE

Thank you.

Comment: Show how you setup this bar button item.

Comment: I mean you need to update your question with the code used to create and setup the edit button.

Comment: No code was used to setup the edit button. It was dragged-and-dropped onto a navigation bar. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There's a much better way, a standard way, to get an Edit/Done button.

`UIViewController` provides a standard Edit/Done button that is already hooked into the `editing` property of the view controller.

A common usage is as follows:

Inside the `viewDidLoad` method of your view controller, use the standard button:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButtonItem
```

Put the `editButtonItem` wherever you actually need it.

Then, instead of setting up your own action, simply override the `setEditing(_:animated:)` method:

```
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)

    if (editing) {
        // user just tapped the Edit button (it now says Done)
    } else {
        // user just tapped the Done button (it now says Edit)
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Can this standardized button be added to a nav bar?

Comment: 2. Will this clear up the sloppy animation I encountered?

Comment: 1. That's what the code in my answer does. It adds the button to the right side of the nav bar. 2. Most likely. It depends on what you do inside the `setEditing` method.

Comment: Does this require that I remove my button in the IB?

Comment: The statement meant to go in the viewDidLoad method doesn't seem to create and place a button in the nav bar.

Comment: The line in `viewDidLoad` does at the button to the nav bar if the view controller is placed in a navigation controller. You should not be adding your own nav bar to the view controller (assuming that is what you are doing). And yes, that line means you should not add your own button or add your own action.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but why is it bad to add my own nav bar? Also, when I removed my nav bar and ran the code, the button doesn't appear.

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm looking to add this button to the top right of one of my tab bar controller views.

Comment: As I said, you need to put the view controller into a navigation controller. That is the proper way to get a nav bar and toolbar (if needed).